# UICollectionView cell didselect flip animation, View is missing

Tags: ios, animation, uicollectionview

UICollectionView cell flip animation on didSelect method should flip with Detailed information on the of the clicked index cell and if user want to go original view should be able to see on cell.
I am using

```
 UICollectionViewCell* cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0
                        options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                     animations:^
     {

         [UIView transitionFromView:cell.contentView
                             toView:cell.contentView
                           duration:.5
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                         completion:nil];
     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {

     }
     ];
```

Comment: can you post the all code in the didselect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code the animation removes your from view and show the to view.So, in the collection if the content view is removed then how it come back.
So, don't remove the view, just hide it.

Please use the below code

```
CVCell* cell1 = (CVCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[UIView transitionWithView:cell1.contentView
                  duration:5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:^{

                    if (cell1.isred) {
                     cell1.isred = NO;
                        cell1.greenview.hidden = NO;
                        cell1.redView.hidden=YES;
                    } else {
                        cell1.isred = YES;
                        cell1.greenview.hidden = YES;
                        cell1.redView.hidden=NO;
                    }

                } completion:nil];
```

greenview is first view and redview is second which are added on the cell.
Now when fliped first greenview is shown and redview is hidden and next time viceversa

You can try other animation

```
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    animation.delegate = self;
    animation.duration = 2.6f;
    animation.timingFunction = UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut;
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animation.startProgress = 0.1;
    animation.endProgress = 1.0;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
    animation.type = @"cube";//---
animation.subtype = (cell1.isred)?kCATransitionFromLeft:kCATransitionFromRight;
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
                    if (cell1.isred) {
                     cell1.isred = NO;
                        cell1.greenview.hidden = NO;
                        cell1.redView.hidden=YES;
                    } else {
                        cell1.isred = YES;
                        cell1.greenview.hidden = YES;
                        cell1.redView.hidden=NO;
                    }
}];

[cell1.contentView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"Cameraanimation"];
```